# Slicing a Pandas df based on column values

Tags: python, pandas

How would you do the following?

- For customers with churn=1, take the average of their last 3 purchases based on the month they leave. E.g. Churn_Month=3, then average last 3 purchases: from Mar, Feb and Jan if available. Sometimes would be 2 or 1 purchase.
- For customers with churn=0, take the average of their last 3 purchases when available, sometimes would be 2 or 1 purchase.

And put it all in one pandas Dataframe. See **Expected Output**

**Available information**

**df1:** Here you'll find transactions with customer id, date, purchase1 and purchase2.

```
    ID  DATE        P1  P2
0   1   2003-04-01  449 55
1   4   2003-02-01  406 213
2   3   2003-11-01  332 372
3   1   2003-03-01  61  336
4   3   2003-10-01  428 247
5   3   2003-12-01  335 339
6   3   2003-09-01  367 41
7   2   2003-01-01  11  270
8   1   2003-01-01  55  102
9   2   2003-02-01  244 500
10  1   2003-02-01  456 272
11  5   2003-03-01  240 180
12  4   2002-12-01  156 152
13  5   2003-01-01  144 185
14  4   2003-01-01  246 428
15  1   2003-05-01  492 97
16  5   2003-02-01  371 66
17  5   2003-04-01  246 428
18  5   2003-05-01  406 213
```

**df2:** Here you'll find customer ID, whether they leave the company or not and the month when they left (E.g. 3.0 = March)

```
    ID  Churn   Churn_Month
0   1       1   3.0
1   2       0   0.0
2   3       1   12.0
3   4       0   0.0
4   5       1   4.0
```

**Expected Output:**

Mean of P1 and P2 by ID, merged with df2 information. ID will be the new index.

```
ID  P1      P2      Churn   Churn_Month
1   190.6   236.6    1         3.0
2   127.5   385      0         0.0
3   365     319.3    1         12.0
4   269.3   264.3    0         0.0
5   285.6   224.6    1         4.0
```

Comment: Couple questions. Does `ID` refer to the customer? What is `P1` and `P2`? Also, what have you tried/where are you getting stuck?

Comment: ID refers to Customer and P1 and P2 are purchases. I don't know where to start.

Comment: In your expected output you have a `Churn_Month` of `4.0` but in your `df2` that doesn't exist. Is this a typo?

Comment: Yeah, it was a typo, just fixed.

Comment: Are the results for `ID == 1` right? `190.6` and `236.6` seem low if the average is supposed to be based on the last 3 months. `ID == 5` seems low too.

Comment: Yeah, based on the last 3 months. Customer left in Mar, so the average would be calculated from Mar, Feb and Jan.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189023/discussion-between-pepe-and-ian-thompson).

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some extra details were necessary here. First, when `Churn == 1` assume that the customer left. Using `df2` you can determine which month they left and remove any data that occurred after. From there it's pretty straight forward in terms of grouping, aggregating, and filter the data.

```
# merge
df3 = df1.merge(df2)

# convert DATE to datetime
df3.DATE = pd.to_datetime(df3.DATE)

# filter rows where month of (DATE is <= Churn_Month and Churn == 1)
# or Churn == 0
df3 = df3.loc[
    ((df3.Churn == 1) & (df3.DATE.dt.month <= df3.Churn_Month)) |
    (df3.Churn == 0)
].copy()

# sort values ascending
df3.sort_values([
    'ID',
    'DATE',
    'P1',
    'P2',
    'Churn',
    'Churn_Month'
], inplace=True)

# groupby ID, Churn
# take last 3 DATEs
# merge with original to filter rows
# group on ID, Churn, and Churn_Month
# average P1 and P2
# reset_index to get columns back
# round results to 1 decimal at the end
df3.groupby([
    'ID',
    'Churn'
]).DATE.nth([
    -1, -2, -3
]).reset_index().merge(df3).groupby([
    'ID',
    'Churn',
    'Churn_Month'
])[[
    'P1',
    'P2'
]].mean().reset_index().round(1)
```

Results

```
   ID  Churn  Churn_Month     P1     P2
0   1      1          3.0  190.7  236.7
1   2      0          0.0  127.5  385.0
2   3      1         12.0  365.0  319.3
3   4      0          0.0  269.3  264.3
4   5      1          4.0  285.7  224.7
```